# Export from Mindtouch wiki software

Tags: mindtouch

I'd like to export all pages from a Mindtouch wiki install to html. I found [this script](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/MindTouch_Administration_Guide/Backup_MindTouch/Export_MindTouch_pages_and_files), but I'm not too sure how to use it. Anyone who has experience with this?

Comment: Link is broken. Looking for a script to export from Mindtouch Core v.9.12.3.

Comment: Copy the link address to the wayback machine and you'll find the latest. It is pretty rude of Mindtouch to get the community to help document their project and then hide the community generated content!http://web.archive.org/web/20120429061746/http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/MindTouch_Administration_Guide/Backup_MindTouch/Export_MindTouch_pages_and_files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- save the script to a file, export_pages.php, and edit it as follows:
  ** replace the $url variable with the corresponding path for your site
  ** replace the username and password that are needed to connect to the site to export your content - this would typically be an administrative user
  ** replace the API key with the API key for your site (can be found in your web\config\mindtouch.deki.startup.xml file)
- create a directory called "pages" where the files will be written (or modify the PHP code to do this for you in case it is not there already)
- run the script: `php.exe export_pages.php`

Also, there is an additional [mindtouch.import.exe](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/MindTouch/Tools/mindtouch.import) tool available if you are running 9.08 and .NET 3.5/Mono 2.4 or later that might suit your needs.

Comment: FYI this script doesn't dump any hierarchy information. If you take a look at the API dumps directly (GET /@api/deki/pages) you can pick out the path attribute and use that to keep hierarchical information as you migrate.